Create World Anchor at Plane Anchor Transform
I'm trying to place a .usda model from Reality Composer Pro to an Anchor on the wall. To preserve the position of my Anchors, I'm trying to convert the initial AnchorEntity() from .plane to .world. There is a reanchor() method for AnchorEntities in the documentation but apparently it's deprecated for visionOS 2.0.

@available(visionOS, deprecated, message: "reanchor(:preservingWorldTransform:) is not supported on xrOS")

The plane AnchorEntity is placed correctly in my tests, but taking its transform and initializing a world anchor there doesn't work as expected. The position of my model is off, looks like it's in the origin/nil despite transforming to the world anchor. This is what I have so far:
Update function:
let planeAnchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical,
                      classification: .wall,
                       minimumBounds: [1.0, 1.0]),
                        trackingMode: .once)

World Anchor Init:
let anchor = getPlaneAnchor()

NSLog("planeAnchor \(anchor.transform)")
    
guard anchor.transform.translation != .zero else {
    return NSLog("Anchor transformation is zero.")
}
          
let worldAnchor = WorldAnchor(originFromAnchorTransform: anchor.transformMatrix(relativeTo: nil))
       
NSLog("worldAnchor \(worldAnchor.originFromAnchorTransform)")

Tracking Session:
case .added:
    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1))
    model.transform = Transform(matrix: worldAnchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
            
    worldAnchors[worldAnchor.id] = worldAnchor
    anchoredEntities[worldAnchor.id] = model
    contentRoot.addChild(model)

Debug:
// planeAnchor Transform(scale: SIMD3<Float>(0.99999994, 0.99999994, 0.99999994), rotation: simd_quatf(real: 1.0, imag: SIMD3<Float>(1.5511668e-08, 0.0, 0.0)), translation: SIMD3<Float>(-1.8068967, 6.8393486e-09, 0.21333294))

// worldAnchor simd_float4x4([[0.99999994, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.99999994, 3.1023333e-08, 0.0], [0.0, -3.1023333e-08, 0.99999994, 0.0], [-1.8068967, 6.8393486e-09, 0.21333294, 1.0]])


In visionOS, transform matrix of RealityKit's AnchorEntity(.plane) is hidden by API design. If you insert the print(planeAnchor.transform.matrix) method in your app's code you'll always see just identity matrix values. That's why the reanchor(..) method is deprecated in visionOS. Therefore, you must use ARKit's PlaneAnchor's transform matrix instead.
You need a real Vision Pro device to run this code:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
import ARKit

@Observable class PlaneAnchorTracking {
    let session = ARKitSession()
    let planeTracking = PlaneDetectionProvider(alignments: [.vertical])
        
    func runArSession() async {
        Task {
            try? await session.run([planeTracking])
        }
    }
    func getTransform() async -> simd_float4x4? {
        let transform = planeTracking.allAnchors.first?.originFromAnchorTransform
        return transform
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    let rkcb = realityKitContentBundle
    let worldAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    let planeAnchorTracking = PlaneAnchorTracking()
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            if let sphere = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: rkcb) {
                sphere.scale *= 5
                
                if let transform = await planeAnchorTracking.getTransform() {
                    worldAnchor.transform.matrix = transform
                }
                worldAnchor.addChild(sphere)
                rvc.add(worldAnchor)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await planeAnchorTracking.runArSession()
            }
        }
    }
}

